# php/javascript/html - UI for verly large number of dynamic selections

Tags: javascript, php, user-interface

I have a page that displays a large number of selectable items dynamically, fetched from a database. For example, I have:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| name | address | <some other values> |
+--------------------------------------+
```

And I have more than 1000 of these items fetched from the database.

The user is supposed to select one or more of these, then a button is pressed to perform some function (which is not relevant to the question).

What techniques can I employ to make this User Interface effective and efficient?

Comment: Displaying 1000 "anything" is not going to be user friendly. Can you provide filters for this data so they can search for the value(s) they need?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise. I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [redit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to SO and we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, there's an excellent table plugin called [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/), that is really nothing more than a table which is a known and expected way to solve your particular problem, but the plugin comes with many use cases solved out of the box (such as responsive styling, pagination, column reordering and styling) if you can afford its size.

Answer (score 0):

Well i think everyone will have its own preferences so i give you mine.

il like to use Datatables : https://datatables.net/examples/api/select_row.html

This example has selection several row at once.